# How do I match alt + 0160 (none breaking space) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to check spans for the character that is printed when you hold alt and press 0160 on the numpad (none breaking space)

`if (myspan.innerHTML == " ")` doesn't work

Comment: you are checking if innerHTML = " " ... dont you want to find " " within innerHTML ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `innerHTML`, it should be contained in the string as `&nbsp;` or `&#160`.

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript, this is the normal way to get Unicode code points:

```
if (myspan == "\u00a0") // decimal is 0160
```

..but seems these may be normalized when put in HTML or used in `innerHTML` as `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(myspan.innerHTML.match(/&nbsp;/g))
or
alert(myspan.innerHTML.indexOf('&nbsp;'))
```